# Submit button is not displayed on screen with <s:submit> tag of struts2

Tags: struts2

When I use s:submit tag of Struts2 then no submit button is being displayed on screen. If I use customized css button then it displays perfectly.

I have to use "s:submit" to send control to specific method in my Action file. I searched on internet and I got to know that "s:submit value="Submit" method="myMethod"  will do the trick inside "s:form" tags.
But I can't do that since button is not displayed at all.

Am I missing something ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since the submit button tag works, we'd probably need more details. Unrelated, but you don't need the submit button tag to make a working submit button--all the tag does is render HTML, which you can duplicate.

Comment: Yeah that's true. My requirement is to have multiple submit buttons which can send control to different methods of action class. When I searched on internet I found that this can be achieved easily using s:submit method="myMethod1".

Comment: Surprisingly, all other struts tags like textbox, select, reset button etc. are being dispalyed, only submit tag doesn't work. :(

Comment: Without any further details it's impossible to help. If nothing else, check the server logs for a JSP error, check your CSS, etc. There's nothing here that can be used to help. You could also create a *complete* minimal example that shows the failure and post a link to the repo.